# How to filter posts by tag in Hexo?

Tags: javascript, generator, ejs, static-site, hexo

Using the static site generator [Hexo](https://hexo.io/) I need to display all posts which are tagged as `featured` on the landing page (index.ejs).

The tags are defined in the individual post files:

```
title: Lorem
tags: 
- featured
- web
```

The code to iterate over all posts looks like this:

```
<% page.posts.each(function(item){ %>
    // TODO: Only insert post if it contains tag 'featured'
    <%- partial('_partial/project-excerpt', {item: item}) %>
<% }); %>
```

The function [`is_tag`](https://hexo.io/docs/helpers.html#is-tag) can only be used with the current page. The functionality needed would be `if page.is_tag('featured') …`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To display **all** posts on index page, you have to access `site` object and not `page` because `page` object only have a defined number of posts (`per_page` variable in `config.yml`).

And to filter only posts tagged with "features", you can use this query

```js
site.tags.findOne({name: 'featured'}).posts.forEach(function(post) {
    // do what you have to do with each post
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using it like this `<%site.tags.findOne({name: 'featured'}).posts.sort('date', -1).limit(5).each(function(post) {%>
  <%- partial('_partial/project-excerpt', {item: post}) %>
<% })%>`

Comment: Thank you! How would you set up a page to display all posts that belong to a certain tag?

Comment: Short answer: create a new hexo page with a layout `custom-tag-layout` , create the layout (file) `custom-tag-layout`, use this query to get all the posts and build the html. If you need more information, create a question, I'll answer it.